# Java GUI designing outline?

Tags: java, user-interface

I made a program in C# and I was trying to port it over to java.  The design of the GUI is this: http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/7728/34685005.png

The faded separator lines starting after Client Downloader passing through Version 1.0 and stopping before Client Downloader. Are those lines available in java? I'm using jFormDesigner and I'm unsure if those lines are there.

If they are available what are they called? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you are trying something complex I would suggest not use a GUI building tool and instead code it by hand.

Look into a Title Border here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

It will give you the part on the top.  You might need to create a custom version to get the "Version 1.0", text or there might already be a third party lib somewhere that has that capability.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [SwingX JXTitledSeparator](http://www.swinglabs.org/hudson/job/Release%20Build/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTitledSeparator.html).

Comment: Looks like the SwingLabs link is down at the moment.  This might be useful, but I don't think it will put the text at the bottom, it just lets you add an icon separate from the text. At least as far as I can tell.